# How to get the absolute url of img elements from an unordered list in JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to extract the absolute urls from the image attributes in the unordered list. But am unable to do so.
 I only want the image links in the unordered list not the whole site.

```html
<ul class="bjqs">
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/8.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/aeration-1.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/DesalinationIII-1.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/Energy-the-global-view-1.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/Exergy-1.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/Exergy-2.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/Medical-Engg-1.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/Phovoltaic-Systems-1.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/Phovoltaic-Systems-2.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/solar-1.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/solar-2.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/solar-3.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/solar-4.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/solar-5.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/solar-6.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider_img/solar-7.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption" /></li>
</ul>
```

Below is what I have tried so far. But this only gives me the first link. Not the others.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("example.org").get();

    Elements ec = doc.select("ul.bjqs");

    for (Element e : ec) {
        System.out.println(e.select("li").select("img").attr("src"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "extract the absolute urls"? In your unordered list there are urls starting from images/ (i.e. relative urls). You can easily extract them with JSoup. Take a look there: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsoup/jsoup_extract_attribute.htm

Comment: @jkonst I have edited the question. What I mean by absolute url is the complete link. The whole address not just the path. I have no clue how to get the srcs since they are inside a list. My code just does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first selector is wrong. Use this to get a list of all images:

```
Elements images = doc.select("ul.bjqs > li > img");
for (Element e : images) {
    System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
}
```

This will print all relative URLs in your HTML. To get the absolute URLs you can use [`URI.resolve()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve-java.lang.String-) with your base URL:

```
String url = "http://example.org/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

URI uri = new URI(url);
Elements images = doc.select("ul.bjqs > li > img");
for (Element e : images) {
    String relative = e.attr("src");
    System.out.println(uri.resolve(relative));
}
```

This will print the absolute URLs of the images.